# How to bypass login page of remote server if i know the user name and password using servlet

Tags: servlets

Lets say I am redirecting a request to remote server using servlet. For remote server I know the user name and password , how can I bypass the remote login page and directly go to the desired page? I tried to set username and password in session but it's not working. Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: Session has nothing to do with a remote server, now does it? And this sounds shady.

Comment: thanks for coming back.Yes you are right. Session has nothing to do with remote server. Now I am able to by pass the login page by rewriting URL of remote server .I am passing user name & password in URL as below : http://remoteserver:8080/MyHomePage?userName=abc&Password=xyz. Is there any way I can hide user name and password while sending request. (I cannot change remote login page as its common for all)

Comment: You can't hide it for real.  Doing login stuff over plain http (rather than https) is an extremely bad idea. Even if you hide it from being in the address bar, its going to be sent as plain text and can be intercepted.

Comment: Sites with login pages should not allow the user to use http to login. They should require https.